# How do you run internet files

Tags: internet

I have been wanting to ask this Question for ages now.I want to download for example "Chrome" I have downloaded it but how do i Execute it.Nothing has worked.:(
Can someone please help me?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43500/discussion-on-question-by-kyle-how-do-you-run-internet-files).

Comment: Please note that Stackexchange question are supposed to be as detailed as possible - usually a little more elaboration beyond *nothing has worked* is requested... and is also of use for helpful answers. Please edit the question itself and do not clutter the info in many comments. See also helpcenter and tour if you haven't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you indicate that you have installed chrome directly from google.com, i am disappointed to tell you that the version of chrome you are attempting to install will not work on the pi as it has been designed to operate on 32 or 64 bit processors and not the arm architecture. I am also sorry to tell you that google does not have a version of chrome that will run on the pi without you running android on the pi first. But what you can do is install chromium-browser which is just like chrome and runs on a similar codebase, but instead is maintained by the community.

```
wget -qO - http://bintray.com/user/downloadSubjectPublicKey?username=bintray | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://dl.bintray.com/kusti8/chromium-rpi jessie main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser -y
```

you may read more about the browser and its installation process [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=121195)

To answer your new question, *why doesn't roblox run on the pi*
well there are many reasons that you will not be able to get roblox on the pi, the first and foremost being that it is quite a lot slower than the minimum specifications for roblox, which pretty much rules out any software solution. But even if you still wanted to run roblox on the pi,roblox does not support linux natively. and although there is third party software that will allow roblox to run on linux. They all require wine support, and run on x86 binaries, which you will not be able to run on the pi as it is  not an amd or intel cpu but one made by arm, similar to what you'd find in a phone. But if you still felt the need to atleast attempt to install rob lox on your pi i would say that your best chance of doing so would be to install android on your pi by following [this](https://www.squirrelhosting.co.uk/hosting-blog/hosting-blog-info.php?id=22) tutorial, then by installing roblox through the playstore.

Comment: Thank you but you do know that is an example. :)

Answer (score 0):

it depends really, you can use `apt-get install`
or you can download a .deb file, if that is the case you can do `dpkg -i filename.deb` if it says you have missing dependencies do `apt-get -f install`